# Oscilloscopes - Comparing Traces

Tags: oscilloscope, troubleshooting

I'm new to Oscilloscopes and so this question may be a simple one. We have a Rigol DS1104Z Oscilloscope and would like to compare the same point in the circuit at different times as the voltage changes based on the type of input. We would like to save these traces, open them as separate channels, so we can line them up and visually compare them.

We have tried saving off the waveforms as "wave" or "trace" output types but cannot figure out how to load both of these onto the oscilloscope at the same time to compare them. Perhaps this is not possible on this oscilloscope. But say you wanted to characterize the voltage changes for a particular pin on a touch screen microcontroller based on various user input. Theoretically, how would you compare two different "inputs" side by side for that same pin? Is that something you could accomplish on the oscilloscope?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on what you really need saving screenshots or using the ref functionality might be useful

Comment: Every decent scope has the ability to save waveform to a reference memory for comparison.

Comment: @laptop2d, but usually only a small number of them (1 or 2 or 4).

Comment: Most scopes have the ability to export data usually to excel format or possibly doc. Import them into excel and plot them on top of each other.

Comment: Many oscopes can and some can't do this. I do all my analysis on my computer though. Your scope does have VISA functionality, which is a library allowing you to send commands to the scope. You can use these commands to pull data, set your settings, detatch the front panel... Time investment to write? Yes. Worth it? Yes.

Comment: Why don't you save both traces on a USB stick (there's a port at the front for that) and then compare them side-by-side on a PC ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I used the reference waveform functionality (which I was unaware of before) to save and compare the waveform at other points in time. As a follow up question, @FakeMoustache, what software do you use to view the traces?

Comment: You don't need special software if you save the traces as a PNG image for example. Then you can just use whatever image viewer you prefer.

Comment: A great hack to do a screenshot on the DS1104Z from a computer connected over Ethernet....

https://hackaday.io/project/5807-driverless-rigol-ds1054z-screen-capture-over-lan

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean -- thanks! And thanks for the hackaday link -- I'll look into setting that up to give me multiple options.